# Reading Number of "Strings" in TTS

Tags: java, android, for-loop, while-loop, text-to-speech

I have number of `String`s, which contain 5 sentences each. Now, I want to pass these to the android Text To Speech, one by one, one at a time. Which means, the first String get passed to the engine, and the second text should be passed once the engine has completed speaking. Below is my code.

```
List<String>textCollection = new ArrayList<String>();

//Add sentences to 'textCollection '. Code removed//

for(int i=0;i<textCollection.size();i++)
{
    while(tts.isSpeaking())
    {

     }

    Toast.makeText(Talk.this, ""+i, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    new SpeakTheText().execute(textCollection.get(i));

}

//This class will speak the text
    private class SpeakTheText extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String>
    {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            tts.speak(params[0], TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
            return null;
        }

    }
```

Now, unfortunately, what is happening is unexpected. The Voice engine just speak text from here and there, not in order! It never speaks the first text, just pick a text from somewhere and read it. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to change parameter of tts

```
tts.speak(params[0], TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);
```

in my application work workwell.

Comment: TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH remove this.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use AsyncTask for this.

Make your class implement `OnUtteranceCompletedListener`

Initiate your TextToSpeech object like this:

```
textToSpeech = new TextToSpeech(context, this); // this being the class that implements OnUtteranceCompletedListener.
```

Then, once your textToSpeech object finishes a given string, it will invoke the `onUtteranceCompleted` method where you can tell your textToSpeech object to speak the next sentence if you have any.

Alternatively, you can use the `QUEUE_ADD` flag instead of the `QUEUE_FLUSH` flag. This will add the new text to the end of the queue, rather than replacing the existing text with new text.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. Can you please provide me a bit more clear code sample please? Queue add might not work, because the text will exceed 4000 characters (the maximum TTS character number)